# Get Facebook's Application Access Token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have to use Facebook's notification for my web app.
Facebook Graph API requires the Application Access Token for this action.

Is there a way to get this token  by code (C# SDK) or is this generated by Facebook a single time?
Is this token static (and secret) or with expire datetime?

For info: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ - App Token, not User Token!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The answer is the dynamic way by code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get( "oauth/access_token", new
{
  client_id = <myAppID>,
  client_secret = <mySecretID>,
  grant_type = "client_credentials"
} );

var apptoken = result.access_token;
```

Or by the combination or appid|secretid

Comment: This worked for me when getting the access token for an application

Comment: Outdated, first need redirect_uri parameter and client_secret should not be passed with client_credentials.
use : var fb = new FacebookClient("appid|secretid");

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the concatenation of id and secret with a pipe symbol in the middle:

```
app_id|app_secret
```

This is actually how the PHP SDK creates the app access token internally, so there should be no question about the reliability of this method. (From other endpoints where you actively query for an app access token you might get another token that does not match this scheme though.)

Comment: Thanks four your answer, but I think it's not the correct information.
The left part (app_id) is the same as Facebook's Access Token Tool shows. But the right part differs from the app_secret. 
Also it does not work with this combination. Just the combination shown in the Access Token Tool works.

Answer (score -3):

you can investigate the getApplicationAccessToken method as in another c# sdk project from github

https://github.com/barans/FacebookCsharpSdk/blob/master/FacebookCSharpSDK/FacebookClient/FacebookClient.cs